# When should I call add_settings_section and add_settings_field?

Tags: actions, settings-api

All of the examples I've seen for `add_settings_section` & `add_settings_field` have them being called on the `admin_init` action. This means that they're being called when loading every single admin page.

However, my understanding is that they're only used when rendering the options page on which they're displayed. Is there any reason no to put all calls to `add_settings_section` & `add_settings_field` in the callback function given to `add_menu_page`?

I'm wondering because I've got a plugin where the selection of fields to display is determined by a call to an external API. I certainly don't want to have to do this on every admin page load. Even if I cache the result of the API call in a transient that's going to expire every so often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `add_settings_section` and `add_settings_field` any time before you `do_settings_sections`:

```
add_action( 'my_plugin_add_settings_sections', function() {
    wp_remote_get( ... );
    add_settings_section( ... );
    add_settings_field( ... );
});

// On the plugin settings page output
do_action( 'my_plugin_add_settings_sections' );
do_settings_sections( ... );
```

You'll still want to `register_setting()` earlier though because that custom hook won't be fired when your settings are saved, so you want to make sure sanitize callback is in place, probably `admin_init`.